# Fitting content to window height

Tags: css

I have this css:

```
html,body {margin:0;}

#nav {
  height:30px;
  background:#FFF;
  background:red;
}

#content {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:30px;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

I'm trying to have a nav bar at the top (the red part) and the content area underneath (the green part) should just fill the remaining space but as you can see the height is more than the window height creating a scroll. How can I overcome this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dcr5yty/5/

Comment: Yes because you have one dive that is 100% of the height of the window and another div that adds 30px to that height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `height 100%`. Use a `bottom: 0`. Because it will be 100% height of the container. Which is the body, so 100% body height means. covering the whole document if position top = 0. Since you have it 30px top. It will have a scrollbar for 30px.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dcr5yty/6/

```
#content {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:30px;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:green;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that works properly...for example if there is a bunch of content it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/2dcr5yty/7/

Comment: If you have more content than that fits. You have to add a `overflow: scroll` or something to make it scrollable.

Comment: thanks - the only reason I had height:100% in there was because it was a fix for something else and then I forgot about it. Will tick soon.